# Book/ Monograph on graph minor theory [Reference request]

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I want to learn graph minor theory. Now i have read the very basic things and the overview from the book of R.Diestel but proceeding further is getting difficult.

Please suggest books/monographs/lecture notes on graph minor theory. In case there is none, please suggest a systematic way to learn the concepts.

Comment: Have you looked at [this monograph/survey by Lovász](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2006-43-01/S0273-0979-05-01088-8/home.html)? (Not sure if it fits the bill)

Comment: Yes. Probably, this article would be more helpful when i have a good grasp on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not actually lecture notes, but perhaps you can produce them yourself.

Here is a link to [videos from a course](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jfgeelen/CO749/lectures.html) taught by Jim Geelen at UWaterloo.